# Como transformar um Array de Objetos em um Array Simples? Javascript

Tags: javascript, array, arraylist

eu queria saber como eu faço pra transformar um Array de Objeto para um Array Simples somente com um determinado vaor..

Eu tenho isto:

```
const names = [
  {id:0, name:"Jean"}, 
  {id:2, name:"Ricardo"}, 
  {id:4, name:"Letiiicia"}, 
  {id:5, name:"Dai"}, 
  {id:7, name:"Tamy"}, 
  {id:10, name:"Abeu"},
```

Eu queria retornar isto para:

```
const names /*ou um novo array, não sei*/ = ['Jean','Ricardo','Leticia','Dai','Tamy','Abeu']
```

Um novo `array` somente com os `names`. Alguem poderia me ajudar ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O mais simples é utilizar a função [`map` de Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), que foi precisamente para esse tipo de situações que foi criada. Esta permite-lhe obter um novo array com base numa transformação do array corrente.

No seu caso seria algo como:

```
names = persons.map(function(person){
    return person.name;
});
```

Em que `persons` seria o array de objetos que tinha inicialmente. O `map` irá chamar a função passada para cada elemento do array, e construir um novo com os retornos obtidos para cada elemento.

Com [Arrow Functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) fica ainda mais direto, simples e fácil de ler:

```
names = persons.map(person => person.name);
```

Que podemos ler da seguinte forma: `persons` é mapeado sendo que cada `person` passa a ser `person.name`.

Veja a funcionar:

```js
const persons = [
  {id:0, name:"Jean"}, 
  {id:2, name:"Ricardo"}, 
  {id:4, name:"Letiiicia"}, 
  {id:5, name:"Dai"}, 
  {id:7, name:"Tamy"}, 
  {id:10, name:"Abeu"}
];
  
const names = persons.map(person => person.name);
console.log(names);
```

Comment: Muitissimo obrigado, Isac <3

Answer (score 2):

Uma forma de fazer é a seguinte:

```
var novoArray = []

for (i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
   novoArray.push(names[i].name);      
}
```

Comment: Obrigado Paulo
Consegui!!

Answer (score 2):

Você pode fazer isso:

```
function myFunction(){

const obj = [
  {id:0, name:"Jean"}, 
  {id:2, name:"Ricardo"}, 
  {id:4, name:"Letiiicia"}, 
  {id:5, name:"Dai"}, 
  {id:7, name:"Tamy"}, 
  {id:10, name:"Abeu"}]

const names = obj.map(function(item) {
  return item['name'];
});

alert(names);
}
```

Comment: Obrigado Fernando!!

Answer (score -2):

> 

```js
const persons = [
  {id:0, name:"Jean"}, 
  {id:2, name:"Ricardo"}, 
  {id:4, name:"Letiiicia"}, 
  {id:5, name:"Dai"}, 
  {id:7, name:"Tamy"}, 
  {id:10, name:"Abeu"}
];
let result = []

for(const r of persons) {
  result.push(r.name)
}
  console.log(result)
```

Comment: outra forma com (for of)

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).